# how to Create Pivot Table at another xlfile via VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I want to create Pivot table at another xlfile, but when I Define Pivot Cache it doesn't work
Can anyone know reason?

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim date_sheet As String
Dim csv_sheet As String
Dim ptl_workbook As String
Dim csv_workbook As String
Dim insert_day As String

Sub AOI_PTL_Updater()

    Dim rng As Variant
    Dim myrng As Range
    Dim mypath As String
    Dim ptl_last_r As Integer
    Dim csv_last_r As Integer
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    insert_day = Application.InputBox("ex) 20201217", "Enter the day", Left:=1000, Top:=800, Type:=2)
    date_sheet = Right(insert_day, 2)
    csv_sheet = InputBox("Ex) 3-1-1", "Enter sepcifitc data name", , 2000, 4000)
    mypath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & insert_day & "\"
    csv_workbook = Dir(mypath & csv_sheet & ".csv")
    ptl_workbook = "AOI_Report.xlsm"
    
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=mypath & csv_workbook

        Rows("1:6").Delete Shift:=xlUp
    
        With Columns("B:B")
            .Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Insert Shift:=xlToRight
            .Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        End With
        
        Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = "CRD"
        Range("C1").FormulaR1C1 = "Pannel"
        Range("D1").FormulaR1C1 = "Part_number"
        Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "Real_NG"
    
    
    csv_last_r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    Set myrng = Range("A2:A" & csv_last_r)
    Windows(ptl_workbook).Activate
    ptl_last_r = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Windows(csv_workbook).Activate
    
    For Each rng In myrng
        rng.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-1],FIND(""["",RC[-1],1)-1)"
        rng.Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(RC[-2],FIND(""["",RC[-2],1)+1,FIND(""]"",RC[-2],1)-(LEN(RC[-1])+2))"
        rng.Offset(0, 3).FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('[" & ptl_workbook & "]PTL_Updater'!R1C3:R" & ptl_last_r & "C3,MATCH(""*""&RC[-2]&""*"",'[" & ptl_workbook & "]PTL_Updater'!R1C10:R" & ptl_last_r & "C10,0))"
        rng.Offset(0, 4).FormulaR1C1 = "=AGGREGATE(9,6,RC20:RC28)"
    Next
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
Call Create_PT

    Windows(csv_workbook).Activate
    ActiveWindow.Close
    Windows(ptl_workbook).Activate
    MsgBox ("PTL Update Complete !")
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub

Sub Create_PT()
    
    'Declare Variables
    Dim PSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PCache As PivotCache
    Dim PTable As PivotTable
    Dim PRange As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim PWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim DWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim destination_range As String
    Dim D_Data As String
       
    
    'Declare Variables
    
    Windows(ptl_workbook).Activate
    Sheets(date_sheet).Select
    Set PWorkbook = Workbooks(ptl_workbook)
    Set PSheet = PWorkbook.Worksheets(date_sheet)

    Set DWorkbook = Workbooks(csv_workbook)
    Set DSheet = DWorkbook.Worksheets(csv_sheet)
    
    destination_range = PSheet.Range("B31").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
 
    'Define Data Range
    LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = DSheet.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    With DSheet.Cells
        D_Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)
    End With
    
    PWorkbook.Activate
    'Define Pivot Cache
    Set PCache = PWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
    (SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:="[" & DWorkbook.Name & "]" & DSheet.Name & "!" & D_Data). _
    CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:="[" & PWorkbook.Name & "]" & PSheet.Name & "!" & destination_range, _
    TableName:="PTL-data")
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a very useful description of the problem you're having when you run your code.  What is the exact error message, and on which line?

Comment: @TimWilliams
Line : at the last section 'Define Pivot cache..
Error Message : "A '13' runtime error has occurred. Format mismatch."

Comment: Is "AOI_Report.xlsm" where this code runs?